# How do I extract the main image from random articles?

Tags: machine-learning, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, feed

I am trying to build a news aggregation system where I will have to process web pages from new news portals everyday. How can I extract the main image of the news article from the webpages without writing html extraction handlers for each portal. How can I guess which is the main image of an article when most of the pages will have 10-15 random ads and side images in it. I tried selecting the largest image in each page but that did not work out well and gave many false positives

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "main" image on the site. This concept is fully context dependent, in terms of news it could be "the image related to the text", but this is very specific situation - what if there are many images inside the news showing some situation?

As it is very hard to define what you really mean, the machine learning based approach seems reasonable, as "learning by example" should be easier to do.

I would extract the most promising features of each image:

- Its relative size to others
- Its distance from the news container in the DOM of the webpage
- Whether its name containes keywords like "news"; "main"
- whether it does not contain "bad" keywords like "ad", "logo", "menu"

And then train the simplest possible classifier on it (Bayes or Logistic Regression) on some collected set of samples.

Comment: How do I identify the news container? Same method? The element with the most text content?

Comment: Probably smallest (in the sense of inclusion) of div's having the most of the text